# Open Geomagic and run a macro with Matlab System Command - open one instance

Tags: python, matlab, macros, single-instance

I want to run a macro (`.py` code) in a Geomagic software (it is an interactive 3D Design Software) using Matlab system command. I'm calling the system command like this in Matlab:

```
system(['geomagic12.exe ', path.py]);
```

It works great and I can import the files that I need in Geomagic easily; however, I have to do this 100 times and this opens another instance of Geomagic every time. Is there any way for me to modify my code in Matlab in a way that it checks if the Geomagic is open or not? Then, if it is closed, it can open a new instance of Geomagic and run the code, and if it is closed, just run the python code? I really appreciate any help.

Thanks.